# Second adam gather in Ryan Amusments

Tags: bioshock-2

I've gathered the adam from the initial corpse, but where is the second corpse? I've been searching for about 40 minutes but had no luck.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://guides.gamepressure.com/bioshock2/guide.asp?ID=9259) you can see on the map corpses marked with 11 and 15.

[image]

You can also see the 2nd corpse in this video,however to see how to get there you should check the previous parts of the video.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't determine the location of an ADAM corpse, there are two easy ways to locate it.

1. Press and hold the Reload key (R by default), your Little Sister will show you the "scent" of ADAM on your screen. This only works if you have a Little Sister on you, and she hasn't gathered two times already.
2. Press M to show the level's map. You will see ADAM corpses marked by a special sign (looking like dead man's face). This works even if you don't have a Little Sister, but it obviously won't show any bodies if there are none left.

This works on any given level.